# How to colorize a cell using x coordinates in iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uikit, uicolor

I have a `CustomCell` which is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. I have a `scrollView` in it. I'm using this `scrollView`in pagingEnabled mode.

I'm using this code to set contentSize of this `scrollView`

`scrollView.contentsize = CGSizeMake(720,70)`

What i want to do is to colorize backgroundColor of this cell using x coordinates. The color of (5,y) and (10,y) must be slightly different. How can i accomplish that ?

**EDIT:** Well, i cannot directly use `cell.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor];` because that makes all the background red, what i need to for example,starts with light red color and ends with dark red color. So, i have to parse all the screen and set the appropriate color.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to draw the background yourself. The best solution would be to create an offscreen bitmap that is the size of the cell and do your custom drawing in that. Then set the background image for the table cell to that image. I believe that if you use a named UIImage then the OS will cache that for you and reuse it for each cell with that background.

If you need this to be more dynamic, then you need to override the -(void)drawRect: method in a custom subclass for that table view row and perform your custom drawing on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

implement the UIScrollView delegate functions into your CustomCell class and set scrollview delegate to you CustomCell class.

and do this

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    CGPoint point = [scrollView contentOffset];

    if (point.x > 80 && point.x < 300) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    }else if(point.x > 400 && point.x < 700){

        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this...

```
   cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:15.0/255.0 green:122.0/255.0 blue:202.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

This will help you to colorize your text..

Comment: I didn't want to colorize my text, i want to colorize my backgroundColor,thanx anyway

Comment: then just change it a little bit...cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clear]; or you can do this also cell.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor; please check these..

Comment: if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0){
    cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor blueColor];
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
}cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clear];
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; //whichever color u want
cell.backgroundColor = cell.contentView.backgroundColor; Add these codes in cellforrowatindexpath